# Excel VBA Loop x = x + 1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel VBA and i'm trying to make a loop that sums X = X + 1 but when the loop ends it continues with the last X and doesn't starts again.
This is what I have:

```
For I = 1 To 3
    J = 2
    For K = 1 To J * 2 Step 1
        Debug.Print K
    Next K
Next I
```

This is what i get: 1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4 .

What i would like to get is: 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12 .

Thanks for the help provided. I thought this would solve my problem but it's a bit more complicated. I need this because i'm adding coordinates in X, Y, Z format with this code:

```
For I = 1 To 6
X = 0
J = 10

RobApp.Project.Structure.Nodes.Create X = X + 1, 0, 0, J * (I - 1)
RobApp.Project.Structure.Nodes.Create X = X + 1, Range("N34") * 0.15, 0, J * 
(I - 1)

Next I
```

"X = X+1" is the node number. I want it to be sequencial, 1,2,3,4 and so on while J is increasing in the Z coordinate. For example for the first line of code:

```
Node 1 = 0,0,0

Node 2 = 0,0,10

Node 3 = 0,0,20
```

and so on!

Comment: Where is your `X=X+1` ?

Comment: That was the best way I could remember to describe what I want to do!

Comment: If you want to get 12 iterations in your loop with the K index, then it's as simple as `For K=1 to 12`

Comment: As Trimax has said, if you want to print out 1 to 12 do K = 1 to 12.  By doing K = 1 to 4 inside another loop I = 1 to 3, you are printing out 1 to 4 three times which is why you get the output you get.  In other words, K is initialised at 1 each time I loops around to 2 and then 3.  Hope that helps.

Comment: [Why accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting an answer helps other people with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Or rather, use the extra variable X as you originally planned:

```
X = 0
For I = 1 To 3
    J = 2
    For K = 1 To J * 2 Step 1
        X = X + 1
        Debug.Print X
    Next K
Next I
```